# According to files names of a file, duplicate files into anther directory

Tags: python

A file writing some files name list, such as there are files names

```
f1
f2 
f3
```

And In the one directory, there are many files which including those files,such as

```
F2
f1
F3
f2
f3
```

I would like to copy the files which appear in the file list. And my scripts whose error is *TypeError*as below,

```
import sys
import shutil,errno
import os
srcDir = 'Root'
dstDir = 'De'
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
 read_filename = f.read()
f.closed
for files in os.walk(srcDir)
  if files in read_filename:
     shutil.move(srcDir,dstDir)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your exception.

Comment: `f.closed` doesn't do anything (it returns the state of the file); you wanted `f.close()`.. Not that you need it as the `with` statement closes the file for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the first file into a *set* (for fast membership testing). You are also using `os.walk`, which gives you *three* pieces of information, the path to the directory, a list of subdirectories and a list of the files in that directory:

```
import sys
import shutil,errno
import os
srcDir = 'Root'
dstDir = 'De'

with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    read_filenames = {fname.strip() for fname in f}  # set comprehension

for root, directories, files in os.walk(srcDir):
    for filename in read_filenames.intersection(files):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, filename), dstDir)
```

The `.intersection()` call returns all elements in the `read_filenames` set that are also in the `files` list.

Note that I tell `shutil.move()` the *full* path of the file to move to `dstDir`, using `os.path.join()` based on the `root` variable (path of the directory the file is in) and the filename.

Comment: Can not copy the files in the *Root* directory,additionally, *filename* displays the rout not file names. Do you know why? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have *no* idea what you are trying to tell me, sorry.